# how to get a single list element in yaml format

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml

In my python program , I have my string:

```
test = {"Controller_node1_external_port": {"properties": {"fixed_ips": [{"ip_address": "12.0.0.1"}],"network_id": {"get_param": ["ex_net_map_param",{"get_param": "ex_net_param"}]}},"type": "OS::Neutron::Port"}}
```

`yaml.dump(test)` is giving me the output :

```
Controller_node1_external_port:
  properties:
    fixed_ips:
    - {ip_address: 12.0.0.1}
    network_id:
      get_param:
      - ex_net_map_param
      - {get_param: ex_net_param}
  type: OS::Neutron::Port
```

But I want ip_address line as `- ip_address: 12.0.0.1` ( means without flower braces covered)

Desired ouput:

```
Controller_node1_external_port:
  properties:
    fixed_ips:
    - ip_address: 12.0.0.1
    network_id:
      get_param:
      - ex_net_map_param
      - {get_param: ex_net_param}
  type: OS::Neutron::Port
```

Comment: When i am printing your line am getting this test = {"Controller_node1_external_port": {"properties": {"fixed_ips": **[{"ip_address": "12.0.0.1"}]**,"network_id": {"get_param": ["ex_net_map_param",{"get_param": "ex_net_param"}]}},"type": "OS::Neutron::Port"}}
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    test = {"Controller_node1_external_port": {"properties": {"fixed_ips": **[{"ip_address": "12.0.0.1"}]**,"network_id": {"get_param": ["ex_net_map_param",{"get_param": "ex_net_param"}]}},"type": "OS::Neutron::Port"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
yaml.dump(test, default_flow_style=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But as per my application,I want only "[{"ip_address": "12.0.0.1"}]" to have this default_flow_style applicable . Is there any sort of doing this ?

Comment: I think in that case you need to look at the examples here (for custom 'representer') http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Constructorsrepresentersresolvers and you will have to wrap your ip address list in a custom class to distinguish it from ordinary lists

Answer (score 0):

If you start from a YAML file you can just use [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) (disclaimer: I am the author of that upgrade of PyYAML) and do:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_in = """
Controller_node1_external_port:
  properties:
    fixed_ips:
    - ip_address: XXX           # <<< update this
      network_id:
        get_param:
        - ex_net_map_param
        - {get_param: ex_net_param}
  type: OS::Neutron::Port
"""

config = ruamel.yaml.load(yaml_in, ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader)
config['Controller_node1_external_port']['properties']['fixed_ips'][0]\
    ['ip_address'] = '12.0.0.1'
print ruamel.yaml.dump(config,
                 Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper)
```

and get as output:

```
Controller_node1_external_port:
  properties:
    fixed_ips:
    - ip_address: 12.0.0.1      # <<< update this
    network_id:
      get_param:
      - ex_net_map_param
      - {get_param: ex_net_param}
  type: OS::Neutron::Port
```

preserving the flow style mappings/dictionaries (`- {get_param: ex_net_param}`) as well as the non-flow style (`- ip_address: 12.0.0.1`) ones.
The comment was preserved as well.